# Is there any way of using ConstraintLayout's Flow helper widget programmatically?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, constraintlayout-flow

I want to use [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout)'s [Flow](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/helper/widget/Flow) widget but when I search I can't find any example about using [Flow](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/helper/widget/Flow) widget programmatically.

How can I set `constraint_referenced_ids` programmatically?

```xml
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.helper.widget.Flow
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="text1,text2"
        app:flow_horizontalBias="0"
        app:flow_horizontalGap="10dp"
        app:flow_horizontalStyle="packed"
        app:flow_verticalBias="0"
        app:flow_wrapMode="chain"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Have you tried this https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/helper/widget/Flow#setReferencedIds(int[])

Answer (score 5):

This works for me:

My custom `PerkFlow` class:

```kotlin
class PerkFlow(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : Flow(context, attrs) {

fun setup(
    parentView: ViewGroup,
    perks: List<String>
) {
    val referencedIds = IntArray(perks.size)
    for (i in perks.indices) {
        val textView = createTextView(context)
        textView.text = perks[i]
        textView.id = View.generateViewId()

        parentView.addView(textView)
        referencedIds[i] = textView.id
    }
    this.referencedIds = referencedIds
}

private fun createTextView(context: Context): TextView {
    val textView = TextView(context)
    textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 12F)
    textView.setTextColor(context.resources.getColor(R.color.gmm_white))
    return textView
}
}
```

my `xml`:

```xml
  <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

..... (a lot of other code)

  <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/vendor_details_perks_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/vendor_details_favourite">

            <com.perkapp.mobile.views.PerkFlow
                android:id="@+id/vendor_details_perks"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:flow_horizontalBias="0"
                app:flow_horizontalGap="5dp"
                app:flow_horizontalStyle="packed"
                app:flow_verticalBias="0"
                app:flow_verticalGap="2dp"
                app:flow_wrapMode="chain"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

 ..... (a lot of other code)

 </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The setup of the PerkFlow in Fragment:

```kotlin
  binding.vendorDetailsPerks.setup(
            binding.vendorDetailsPerksContainer,
            listOf("apple, banana, blackberries, blueberries, cherries, grapes, lemon, orange, peaches, pear, pineapple, plums, raspberries, strawberries, watermelon ")
        )
```

Hope this helps!

And one more thing: if you call this again (in RecyclerView item, or new data arrives), don't forget to clear the parent view or the elements will be duplicated. I can send that code too if needed.

Comment: Not sure how this works without setting any constraints on the added views. In a similar usage of mine all views will lay on top of each other.

Answer (score 3):

#### Option 1

You can update a [Flow](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/helper/widget/Flow) layout's reference IDs at runtime by means of the [Flow.setReferenceIds(ids:)](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/helper/widget/Flow#setReferencedIds(int%5B%5D)) method.

Note that the [Flow.setReferenceIds(ids:)](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/helper/widget/Flow#setReferencedIds(int%5B%5D)) method (in its current form) does not request a layout so you may need to call [Flow.requestLayout()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#requestLayout()) as well as [Flow.setReferenceIds(ids:)](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/helper/widget/Flow#setReferencedIds(int%5B%5D)).

#### Option 2

You can add and remove Views to/from a [Flow](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/helper/widget/Flow) layout by means of the [Flow.addView(view:)](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/helper/widget/Flow#addView(android.view.View)) and [Flow.removeView(view:)](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/helper/widget/Flow#removeView(android.view.View)) methods.

#### Option 3

If you know all of the Views that you want to place inside of your [Flow](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/helper/widget/Flow) layout ahead of time and you just want to toggle which ones are hidden and displayed on demand, then you're best adding all of the Views to your [Flow](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/helper/widget/Flow) layout ahead of time and just toggling the [visibility](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#setVisibility(int)) of the Views between [GONE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#GONE) and [VISIBLE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#VISIBLE) as needed.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning the need to call `Flow.requestLayout()`.